Recalculate derived data after dynamic and recurring timeout (useEffect and useState?)
I have a custom hook in one of my projects that gets data from an API and then returns a filtered subset of that data.
Each item inside data has a timestamp that determines whether it is active or not.
Right now I get the shortest duration until an item changes and trigger a recalculation inside a timeout inside a useEffect hook.
My hook stores the filtered data with useState and very explicitly manages changes inside the useEffect hook (setFilteredData).
My question is if there is a better way. Would it be better or more idiomatic to use useMemo to derive filteredData?
How would I trigger it to rerun on every timer change in that case?
This is a minimal example with some mock functions to showcase the problem.
import React from "react";

// Mock functions
const getMillisecondsToNextCalculation = () =>
Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
const filterData = (data) => data.filter(Math.random() > 0.5);

const useFilteredData = () => {
  const apiData = useQuery("apiData", fetchApiData);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = React.useState(() =>
    filterData(apiData)
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    const recalculateData = () => {
      const delay = getMillisecondsToNextCalculation();
      if (!delay) return;
    
      // Is this a good practice?
      setFilteredData(filterData(apiData));
    
      // Recursively call the function
      timeout = setTimeout(recalculateData, delay);
    };
    
    recalculateData();
    
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  });

  return {
    filteredData,
  };
};

export default useFilteredData;

Any help or opinions on this would be appreciated!
I tried to use useMemo with a dependency on something I set in the useEffect hook, but that did not work out as I expected.

Yes, it's idiomatic to use a useMemo instead of a useState-useEffect coupling. It get's a little fuzzy though if you need to also instantiate additional side-effects other then computing a derived "state" value. If you are using Redux-Toolkit Query you can also select a filtered subset of values from the cached result, e.g use a selector function to memoized a computed value from the query hook. If you need more help than this can you [edit] to include any RTK-Query code/hooks/etc so we can see what you are working with?

BTW your useEffect hook is missing a dependency array, so it will trigger the effect each render cycle.

Using useMemo to derive filteredData can indeed be a cleaner and more idiomatic approach in this scenario. It allows you to memoize the filtered data and recalculate it only when the dependencies change. However, triggering it on every timer change might require a bit of a different approach.
Here's how you can refactor your useFilteredData hook to use useMemo instead of useState and useEffect, and ensure that it recalculates on every timer change:
import React from "react";

// Mock functions
const getMillisecondsToNextCalculation = () =>
  Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
const fetchApiData = () => {
  // Mock API data fetching sample without using any api
  return [
    { id: 1, timestamp: new Date() },
    { id: 2, timestamp: new Date() },
    { id: 3, timestamp: new Date() },
  ];
};
const filterData = (data) => data.filter((item) => Math.random() > 0.5);

const useFilteredData = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(0);
  const apiData = React.useMemo(() => fetchApiData(), [timer]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimer(timer + 1);
    }, getMillisecondsToNextCalculation());

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [timer]);

  const filteredData = React.useMemo(() => filterData(apiData), [apiData]);

  return {
    filteredData,
  };
};

export default useFilteredData;

